# Show that $\lim_{\epsilon\to0^{+}}\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{\gamma_\epsilon}\frac{f(z)}{z-a} \, dz=f(a)$

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis

> Let $a\in\Bbb C$ and $r>0$ and denote by $B(a,r)\subseteq \Bbb C$ the open ball of center $a$ and radius $r$. Assume that $f:B(a,r)\to\Bbb C$ is a continuous function and for each $\epsilon>0$ let $\gamma_\epsilon:[0,2\pi]\to \Bbb C$ be given by $\gamma_\epsilon(t)=a+\epsilon e^{it}$. Show that 
>   $$\lim_{\epsilon\to0^{+}}\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{\gamma_\epsilon}\frac{f(z)}{z-a} \, dz = f(a).$$

I tried the following
$$\lim_{\epsilon\to0^{+}}\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{\gamma_\epsilon}\frac{f(z)}{z-a}dz=\lim_{\epsilon\to0^{+}}\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{f(a+\epsilon e^{it})}{a+\epsilon e^{it}-a}i\epsilon e^{it} \, dt = \lim_{\epsilon\to0^{+}} \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_0^{2\pi}f(a+\epsilon e^{it}) \, dt$$

If I can change the limit and the integral, then it is obvious. I tried to use the Lebesgue bounded convergence theorem to argue that, since $f:B(a,r)\to\Bbb C$ thus on $B(a,r)$ we have $|f(a+\epsilon e^{it})|\le M$, where M is the maximum of $|f(x)|$ on $B(a,r)$.

Is that valid?

Comment: If $f$ is bounded. Otherwise you'd need to take the maximum on $\overline{B(a,\rho)}$ for some $\rho < r$. But $t \mapsto f(a + \epsilon e^{it})$ converges to the constant function $t \mapsto f(a)$ uniformly as $\epsilon \searrow 0$, no need for big theorems.

Comment: @DanielFischer $f$ is continuous, hence bounded on $B(a,r/2)$.

Comment: @egreg Yes, it's bounded on $B(a,\rho)$ for all $\rho < r$, but not necessarily on $B(a,r)$.

Comment: @DanielFischer Well, it's not restrictive to assume the limit is computed for $0<\varepsilon<r/2$.

Comment: @egreg In the last sentence, the OP writes "… where $M$ is the maximum of $\lvert f(x)\rvert$ on $B(a,r)$". That only works if $f$ is bounded on $B(a,r)$. If it isn't, one looks at a slightly smaller ball - $f$ is bounded on the smaller balls because they are [relatively] compact - and ignores $\epsilon > \rho$.

Comment: @DanielFischer And what's the problem in restricting the function to $B(a,r/2)$? Can this change the limit?

Comment: @egreg There's no problem with that. My point is that the OP's argument *without that small modification* only works if $f$ is bounded on $B(a,r)$.

Answer (score 4):

$f$ is continuous in $a$, therefore for all $\eta > 0$ there exists
a $\delta > 0$ such that
$$
 |f(z) - f(a)| < \eta \text{ for all } z \in B(a, \delta) \, .
$$
Then for $0 < \epsilon < \delta$ 
$$
\left| \frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{\gamma_\epsilon}\frac{f(z)}{z-a} \, dz - f(a) \right| = \left | \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi}(f(a+\epsilon e^{it}) - f(a)) \, dt \right|
\le \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_0^{2\pi} \bigl|f(a+\epsilon e^{it}) - f(a) \bigr| \, dt \\
\le \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_0^{2\pi} \eta \, dt = \eta
$$
and the conclusion follows.

Comment: why should the $i$ still be there?

Comment: @Meitar: Sorry, I don't get what you mean. Which $i$ are you talking of?

Comment: I now got it, thank you for adressing it.

Comment: Would you help me understand under what circumstances absolute convergence means convergence? I mean, looking at that case.

Comment: @Meitar: Sorry, but I don't get what you are asking for. $\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{\gamma_\epsilon}\frac{f(z)}{z-a}$ is a function of the real variable $\epsilon$, and the limit for $\epsilon \to 0$ is computed. How is absolute convergence involved here?

Answer (score 1):

Hint: the function may not be bounded on $B(a,r)$ but it surely is on $\overline{B(a,r/2)}$ (which is compact), so it's not restrictive to assume it is bounded, since we're computing the limit for $\varepsilon\to0$.